# VBA: Copy dynamic range until a specific text

Tags: excel, vba

Firstly, I must emphasize that I am new to `VBA`, working as an auditor and wanting to expand my skills beyond my current work.

I am testing to do a code to summarize a time-sheet and I'm stuck at the part where I copy a range from a pivot table.

So what I want is to copy the range `"N7"` and all the rows below until the text `"Grand total"` appears. Everything between `"Grand total"` and cell `"N7"` is to be copied to cell `"C11"`.

I have no idea where to begin. I though first that i needed use loop, but I'm not sure. I would be grateful for any help!

Thanks,

Comment: Could we see your code up to this point?

Comment: There is not much of a code before, just the code of creating pivo table thorugh macro recorder.

Answer (score 0):

If your grand total is the last row in the sheet calculate the last row of data in the sheet  and go one row up:

```
Dim LastRow as Long
With Worksheets("WorksheetName")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("N7:N" & LastRow-1).Copy
End With
```

That's how you copy that range, do you want to sum the values in the range to put in c11?

Comment: Or use `Match` to locate the grand total row ( in case there is more data below)

Comment: I ran the code and i got the error message "Application-defined or boject-defined error" 

The only thing i changed was the worksheetname. I can't see the text "Grand Total" in the code, a bit confused.